# How to login into Jenkins when I can't login through the general method

Tags: jenkins

I have created my credentials in Jenkins with my email id too, but whenever I try to login through my url i.e., htpps://localhost:portnumber, there is always an issue and the Jenkins home page/login page never shows up..
I'm looking for help..

Comment: I tried to reinstall and login again, at the moment it is working fine, but after a day or two, I can't login....

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution guys,
While setting up jenkins after inserting the security code, you'll be giving your account info, the following step will ask you for your host address. Here you can change or
After this step, you'll be going to your Dashboard, go to Manage Jenkins ==>  Configure System ==> Jenkins URL
Here change it if you need it
It is actually recommended to change it from default 8080 to another one